# Service Date in Process builder is not showing up

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have a process builder, where I am just adding an immediate action to create Opportunity Product then I don't see the field @ServiceDate , is there any reason for the same.

Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Comment: What object does the process start with?

Comment: It is on Opportunity, please check the attachment.

Comment: Isn't it just called Date on Opportunity Product???

Comment: API name `ServiceDate` has user label = `Date` and user labels appear in the point and click UI. See `Setup | Customize | Opportunities | Opportunity Products | Fields` - SFDC has many examples where the OOB API name has no resemblance to the user label - leading to endless confusion